# Can we restrict the usage of an SSL certificate to only a specific protocol?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, network-protocols

I would like to generate a certificate that can be used only for HTTPS.
For example, if I use the same certificate for my web server (HTTPS) and my mail server (IMAPS) using the same certificate, the user can only connect to the web server only via HTTPS.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to avoid the user doing? Or is it the administrator you are trying to avoid doing something?

Answer (score 3):

While creating the certificate you cannot limit the way it can be used. But afterwards, you yourself decide if you want to use it for HTTPS and/or IMAPS.

In your webserver settings you can decide to only allow access via HTTPS and not via HTTP (although it is advicable to use redirection instead of denying HTTP outright).